# NavigationDrawerFragment onbackpressed issue in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**My Menu have following options**

1. fragment A
2. fragment B
3. fragment c

**My fragments**

1. fragment A----subfrag1---subfrag2
2. fragment B----subfrag1---subfrag2
3. fragment c(no sub fragments)

   **onBack works perfectly in following order**
   fragment A----subfrag1---subfrag2 reverse onback pressed.

but problem is

when am go to **fragment A-->B**

**1 time** press onback shows **whitescreen** only

**2 times** press onback then only **shows  fragment A**.

my code is

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position+1)).addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

}



public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = " fragmentA";
            fragment = new fragmentA();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
       case 2:
            mTitle = " fragmentB";
            fragment = new fragmentB();
            final String sid="Active";
            bundle.putString("id", sid);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();              
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle =" fragmentC";
            fragment = new fragmentC();
            bundle.putString("crmadminid", crmadminid);
           fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
break;     


    }

}
```

**onBackPressed code**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

How to avoid 2 times press onback button issue?

Comment: i need to avoid 2 times press onback button @Coas Mckey

Answer (score 0):

I think when you press the back button on fragment B it shows white screen because the fragment is detached , I think the only work around for you is to do some thing like

```
fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, secondFrag);
                    fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragTran.addToBackStack("TAG");
                    fragTran.commit();
```

I think you need to remove .addToBackStack(null) from your code while going from Fragment A to B

Please try this and let me know, it it does help , mark it as answer if not then tell me so that I can update my answer

Comment: what is on fragment B

Comment: i can not understand what you say